# How can i add the Manufacturer Name in Product title?

Tags: product, page-title, magento1.9.0.1

I want to add the Manufacturer into the Product Title like:

"Nike" Shoe XYZ or "Apple" iPhone 5s

The `manufacturer` Attribute is already set in Backend. But i want to import our 15k Products via csv import.

Comment: You can append manufacturer name  in product name into csv using concatenate and then import it. Otherwise you have to include Manufacturer name in every file from where name is appearing.

Comment: Is there no other Chance? Like manipulate an xml or php file?

Comment: You have to change hundreds of php files.

Comment: @AmitGarg Your suggestion does not solve the OP's question, which is to only have the page title changed. Your suggestion will append the data everywhere the product name is displayed, which is not what is asked here. Anyways, concatenating the data like that is poor practice, as it does not leave you room for change later down the line. Also, there is no need to change hundreds of php files. That again only sets you up for later failure when you try and upgrade your site, with too many template files to wade through and upgrade.

Comment: @Maurice I think possible myself, and others may have misinterpreted your requirement, with product title, do you mean the title of the page, or do you mean the name of the product when it is displayed?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have it as "real magento" Product Title then you should join it during import. If it is a pure display issue, then it will be enough to adapt the templates that display product names (e.g. `display/frontend/package/default/template/catalog/prodcut/view.phtml`) or for the other places (categories, sidebars, carts) alike.

There you mostly find something like `$_product->getName()`. That has to be adapted to concatenate Manufacturer and Name.

If you use a helper for the manufacturer it also easy to display a product logo instead of just the manufacturer string.

Comment: is there a good extension? because iam a beginner in magento

Comment: Editing the template files is not the best way forward to accomplish such a task. You can do it via code, as suggested by @AmitBera (although his second suggested code is the way to go, not the usage of the local namespace) - Editing to many template files makes upgrading a site a lot more difficult later down the line. for example, you can extend the core product model, and create a function called getName(), in which you then concatenate the information. This then will make any display layer 'fall into place' as a call to `$_product->getName()` will result in the concatenated information.

Comment: @ProxiBlue it is more than debatable if rewriting the product model (!) for such a little change is better than editing a template file...

Comment: @Simon, depend on the endgame. If you only want the view.phtml to reflect the name change, then yes, however, would it not be better to have the site consistent throughout, and have the name display the same everywhere. Then you start talking about editing many phtml files. Cart, checkout review, order history, emails, just to name a few off the top of my head. If you change the way the data is retrieved, from the model, it will consistently appear the same throughout the site, and you can easily change that in just one place if your needs change.

Answer (score 1):

Maurice, it sounds as if you wish to add the product manufacturer to the product name BEFORE importing to magento correct?

So is it possible in your CSV file you have one column for "name" and one column for "manufacturer"?

If so you can concatenate the date BEFORE you load it into magento using Microsoft Excel

For example if name is column C (Red Basketball Shoe Size 14) and manufacturer is column B (Nike)

1)Make a new column D.
2)in D2, use the formula =concatenate(b2," ",c2)
3)Your end result in d2 will be "Nike Red Basketball Shoe Size 14".
4)You should then copy all of column D, and paste special just the values over all of Column C (name)
5)Make sure you then change c1 back to "name"

Now when you import into magento all your products will have Manufacturer at the beginning of the name.

By doing this BEFORE importing to magento, it will use this data in the Product Url Key (if you did not specify in your file), as well as name on product pages, and product meta page titles by default.

However the downside of this is your category / search listings will all have the manufacturer name at the front of product names too and might look very repetitive to the user's eyes.

The benefit of this approach is you do not risk injuring your magento if you are not confident in your abilities there as well as obtain the SEO benefits you are trying to achieve.